# Display 2d array using ngFor in html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

I have the following list of arrays which needs to be displayed in a p-table in html.

```
[Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(1)]
0: (2) ["abc", "def"]
1: (2) ["ghi", "jkl"]
2: (2) ["mno", "pqr"]
3: (2) ["stu", "vwx"]
4: ["yz"]
```

This needs to be displayed like below using html:

[image]

So how can I write a proper ngFor logic for this in html? Please help

Comment: Long story short. This is a multidimensional array (an array of arrays). Write a function that iterates through the main array and then chooses fields of the table by index in each row. aka when index (i) of the array is 0, select first row and then first spot in the child array goes into the first field, second spot (aka index = 1) goes into the second field etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fcqwea?file=src/app/app.component.html) with two ngFor you can do it

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let el of array| max,let i=index">
      <td *ngFor="let arr of array">
        {{arr[i]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

with pipe you can find max length item and take it base for loop

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'max'
    })
    export class MaxPipe implements PipeTransform {
    
      transform(value: any[]): any {
        var maxlen = 0;
        for (let i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
          if (value[i].length>maxlen) {
            maxlen = value[i].length;
          }
        }
        return  new Array(maxlen); ;
      }
    
    }
```